# Proof that the difference of two positively squared integers never equals 1

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, alternative-proof, proof-explanation

This type of question is usually solved by a proof by contradiction, however I believe I have a direct proof of it, and I would like to know if its correct.

#### Problem : Prove that there does not exist positive integers m and n, such that $$m^2 - n^2 = 1$$

### Proof:

Since $$m, n \in \mathbb{Z^{+}} \implies m \geq 1 \land n \geq 1
$$
Rearranging the first inequality we get.
$$m^2 - n^2 \geq 1-n^2$$
To simplify this inequality we can say $$Since :n^2 \in \mathbb{Z^{+}},       \ \ \exists \ k \in \mathbb{Z^{+}} \ | \ k = n^2$$
$$\therefore m^2 - n^2 \geq 1-k $$

And because $$k=n^2 \implies k \geq 1$$
The right hand side of the inequality is never equivalent to 1, as k is never equal to zero. Therefore because the right hand side of this inequality is never equal to one, we have proved that :

$$m^2 - n^2 \neq 1 \ \ \ \forall m,n \in \mathbb{Z^{+}}$$

#### $$Q.E.D$$

---

Is this direct proof correct? Also if you have any comments or suggestions on my proof-writing, please let me know.

Comment: You assert that $m^2-n^2\geqslant i$ with $i\ne1$ implies that $m^2-n^2\ne1$. This is not so. Otherwise, $j\geqslant i$ with $i\ne1$ would imply that $j\ne1$, right? But $1\geqslant-2$ and $-2\ne1$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1728259/how-to-prove-that-there-are-no-positive-integer-solutions-x-y-to-the-equati/1728277.

Comment: Friendly reminder: if someone answers your question on MSE and you find his/her answer satisfactory, then it is a good idea to vote up any useful answers and accept the best one (if it truly answers your question). I noticed you have asked 12 questions and have only accepted answers to 2 of them. I would recommend you to go back and accept those answers you found most helpful--this gives answerers due recognition and it also lets the MSE community know that your question(s) is/are effectively closed. Just a little FYI.

Comment: @Daniel, thanks for the reminder, I'll go and do that right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the contrapositive may help to produce clearer proof.

Assume that $\exists m,\;n \in {\mathbb{Z}^ + }$ (with $m > n$) such that$${m^2} - {n^2} = 1.$$
It follows that ($ * $) $m - n \in {\mathbb{Z}^ + }$ and$$(m - n)(m + n) = 1$$so that$$m - n = \frac{1}{{m + n}}$$
But then $m - n \notin {\mathbb{Z}^ + }$ contradicting ($ * $). Therefore no such $m,\;n \in {\mathbb{Z}^ + }$ exist $ \bullet $

Answer (score 1):

(i)...$\;0<m\leq n\implies m^2 \leq n^2$ $\implies m^2-n^2\leq 0\implies m^2-n^2 \ne 1.$

(ii)...$\;m>n>0\implies m>n\geq 1\implies [m\geq n+1\land n\geq 1]\implies$ $\implies [m-n\geq 1\;\land m+n\geq (n+1)+1=2 n +1\geq 3)]\implies$ $\implies m^2-n^2=(m-n)(m+n)\geq 1\cdot 3=3\implies m^2-n^2\ne 1.$