# How to prove that there are no positive integer solutions $(x, y)$ to the equation $x^2 - y^2 = 1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Prove the following:

**Theorem.** There are no positive integer solutions $(x, y)$ to the equation
$x^2-y^2=1$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1719001/prove-that-x21-cannot-be-a-perfect-square-for-any-positive-integer-x.

Answer (score 9):

If $x^2 -y^2=1$, then $(x-y) = \frac{1}{x+y} $, since $x$ and $y$ are positive integers $0<\frac{1}{x+y}<\frac{1}{2}$. But since x and y are integers so does $x-y$. Which gives us a contradiction.

Answer (score 4):

$(x^2-y^2)=1 \implies (x-y)(x+y)=1 \implies (x+y) \leq 1$, a contradiction as $x \geq 1$, $y \geq 1 \implies x+y \geq 2$.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another take.

$x^2-y^2=1$ implies $x^2=y^2+1$.

$x^2=y^2+1 > y^2$ implies $x>y$, that is, $x\ge y+1$.

But then $x^2 \ge (y+1)^2 = y^2+2y+1 \ge y^2+2+1 > y^2+1$, since $y \ge 1$.

Thus, $x^2 > y^2+1$, contradiction.

---

Another, more succinct way to express this is:
$$
y^2 < y^2+1 < (y+1)^2
$$
Thus, $y^2+1$ is strictly between two *consecutive* squares and so cannot be a square.

Answer (score 0):

This is Pell's equation for $d=1$. If $d$ is a square, and $d=1$ is, it has only the trivial solutions $(x,y) = (\pm 1, 0)$.

Comment: talk about using a sledge hammer on a mole hill (or whatever actual idiom there is). cool use of the theorem though!